# Calculating field index based on feature attribute value using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, attribute-table, fields-attributes, features, indexing

Is there a way of finding to which field/column a feature attribute belongs?

For example, let's say I know feature[x] has an attribute of 0.17, I also know this must be between fields [12:17].

Can I ask QGIS to return the field name with that attribute for that particular feature?

Answer (score 1):

Wonder if there's a nice, compact way of achieving this but in the meantime, you could use the following function which lets you enter the feature ID and the value you want to search for. It will then output a list of field names which contain the specified value:

```py
def identifyFields(feature_id, value):
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    fields = [field.name() for field in layer.fields()]
    request = QgsFeatureRequest().setFlags(QgsFeatureRequest.NoGeometry)
    for feat in layer.getFeatures(request):
        if feat.id() == feature_id:
            if value in feat.attributes():
                fieldIndex = [i for i, j in enumerate(feat.attributes()) if j == value]
    fieldName = [fields[i] for i in fieldIndex]
    print(fieldName)
```

You can execute it using something like:

```py
identifyFields(1, 0.17)
```